# Is there an algorithm for unique "hashes"

Tags: security, encryption, hash

I'm interested in finding an algorithm that can encode a piece of data into a sort of hash (as in that is impossible to convert back into the source data, except by brute force), but also has a unique output for every unique input. The size of the output doesn't matter.

It should be able to hash the same input twice though, and give the same output, so regular encryption with a random, discarded key won't suffice. Nor will regular encryption with a known key, or a salt, because they would be exposed to attackers.

Does such a thing exist?

Can it event theoretically exist, or is the data-destroying part of normal hash algorithms critical for the irreversible characteristic?

---

What use would something like this be? Well, imagine a browser with a list of websites that should be excluded from the history (like NSFW sites). If this list is saved unencoded or encrypted with a key known on the system, it's readable not just by the browser but also by bosses, wives, etc.

If instead the website addresses are stored hashed, they can't be read, but the browser can check if a site is present in the list.

Using a normal hash function could result in false positives (however unlikely).

---

I'm not building a browser, I have no plan to actually use the answer. I'm just curious and interested in encryption and such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any form of lossless public encryption where you forget the private key.

Comment: I edited the question. I need to be able to get the same output multiple times.

Comment: That would work. I should've thought of that myself * shame * :p

Answer (score 2):

In theory it's impossible for outputs that are shorter than the input. This trivially follows from the pidgeon-hole principle.

You could use asymmetric encryption where you threw away the private key. That way it's technically lossless encryption, but nobody will be able to easily reverse it. Note that this is *much* slower than normal hashing, and the output will be larger than the input.

But the probability of collision drops exponentially with the hash size. A good 256 bit hash is collision free for all practical purposes. And by that I mean hashing for billions of years with all computers in the world will almost certainly not produce collision.

---

Your extended question shows two problems.

> What use would something like this be? Well, imagine a browser with a list of websites that should be excluded from the history (like NSFW sites). If this list is saved unencoded or encrypted with a key known on the system, it's readable not just by the browser but also by bosses, wives, etc.
>
> If instead the website addresses are stored hashed, they can't be read, but the browser can check if a site is present in the list.

Brute force is trivial in this use case. Just find the list of all domains/the zone file. Wouldn't be surprised if a good list is downloadable somewhere.

> Using a normal hash function could result in false positives (however unlikely).

The collision probability of a hash is much lower(especially since you have no attacker that tries to provoke a collision in this scenario) than the probability of hardware error.

So my conclusion is to combine a secret with a slow hash.

```
byte[] secret=DeriveKeyFromPassword(pwd, salt, enough iterations for this to take perhaps a second)
```

and then for the actual hash use a KDF again combining the secret and the domain name.

Comment: Oh that's not true; PANAMA, GOST and HAVAL all output to 256 bits and all have had collision problems.

Comment: I'm obviously talking about an *unbroken* cryptographic hash. But if his crypto gets broken the OP will have a problem no matter if he used lossless encryption or hashing.

Comment: I wouldn't say brute force is trivial. A list of all sites would be pretty large, and the "hash" function could be artifically made slower (by applying it multiple times or with a very large known key) so that brute-forcing would be very slow, while a single lookup would still be fast enough. I agree though that in the real world the chance of collision is probably low enough.

Comment: If a single lookup takes something like 100ms on a medium class CPU(sounds like reasonable delay)  then an attacker who as a decent graphics card can probably try >100 hashes per second. This means he can try >10mio hashes a day. Since the domain popularity is strongly concentrated on relatively few websites he should be able to test all important websites within a day. I'd rather stake my security on a user password than on hashes(or combine both).

Comment: Can all asymmetric algorithms be run on a GPU?

Comment: Probably yes. The question is how efficient is it, and has somebody already done it. But I'm no expert on GPU programming.

Comment: Good starting point for bruteforce: The alexa top 1mio domain list at http://s3.amazonaws.com/alexa-static/top-1m.csv.zip

Answer (score 2):

Given the definition of a hash;

> A cryptographic hash function is a deterministic procedure that takes an arbitrary block of data and returns a fixed-size bit string, the (cryptographic) hash value, such that an accidental or intentional change to the data will change the hash value.

no - it's not theoretically possible. A hash value is of a fixed length that is generally smaller than the data it is hashing (unless the data being hashed is less than the fixed length of the hash). They will always lose data, and as such there can always be collisions (a hash function is considered good if the risk of collision is low, and infeasible to compute.)

Comment: Well, I asked for a *sort of* hash, so that definition doesn't apply. The output doesn't need to be fixed-length or smaller than the input.

Answer (score 1):

Well, any lossless compressor with a password would work.

Or you could [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) your input with some known (to you) text. This would give you something as long as the input. You could then run some sort of lossless compression on the result, which would make it shorter.

Comment: Any secure encryption / hash algorithm will output non-compressible data. If it doesn't, it's not secure.

Comment: You need to compress the input not the output.

Answer (score 1):

you can find a hash function with a low probability of that happening, but i think all of them are prone to [birthday attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack), you can try to use a function with a large size output to minimize that probability

Answer (score 0):

Well what about md5 hash? sha1 hash?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can exist; if you can put anything into them and get a different result, it couldn't be a fixed length byte array, and it would lose a lot of its usefulness.

Perhaps instead of a hash what you are looking for is reversible encryption?  That should be unique.  Won't be *fast*, but it will be unique.

Comment: @daniels, MD5 and SHA1 can have collisions, i.e. two different files/ strings can have the same hash value.  You can mitigate this by including length data in your hash comparisons, but in theory you can still have collisions.

Comment: @CodeInChaos: whether or not the hash is broken or not has nothing to do with collisions.  Collisions will occur; it may be more likely to occur in "broken" hashes where the data to be hashed has some similarities, but it will still happen.

Comment: The probability for a collision in a non broken cryptographic hash of >256 bits is low enough for pretty much everything. The probability of hardware faults is so much higher that you don't need to worry about random collisions occurring. The only problem is an attacker which deliberately crafts input to produce a collision after he has broken the hash algorithm.